# Object-fit: contain, is not filling the entire container and leaves a white space above and below. It is only happening for 1 image

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I have various img tags with height and width set to 180px.
2. I also have set a border around them.
3. I have set object fit: "contain" on each one.

I want the images to fill the entire container so that you CANNOT see any white space between the image and its border.

On all of the images it is working fine but there is one image that is driving me off the wall and I cannot figure out why there is a white space between the image and its border.

PS, I cannot use object fit "cover" because I don't want the image to be cropped and I cannot not use object fit because I need the resizing that I get from object fit.

Here is my HTML :

```html
<img class="tnails" src="zetong-li-mVqTumQH-c0-unsplash.jpg">
<img class="tnails" src="alex-suprun-ZHvM3XIOHoE-unsplash.jpg">
<img class="tnails" src="star_1828884.png">
<img class="tnails" src="star_1828970.png">
<img class="tnails" src="twitter-icon.png">
<img class="tnails" src="magnifying-glass.png">
<img class="tnails" src="linkedin-icon.png">
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.tnails {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

And here is a snapshot it is the first image of the truck:

[image: first image of truck]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `cover`, not `contain`.

**Note:** The first image in the only rectangular image. All the rest are square. If you hade a portrait photo, there would be bars on the sides.

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `cover` | The image keeps its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit. |
| `contain` | The image keeps its aspect ratio, but is resized to fit within the given dimension. |
| `fill` | The image is resized to fill the given dimension. If necessary, the image will be stretched or squished to fit. |
| `none` | The image is not resized. |
| `scale-down` | The image is scaled down to the smallest version of none or contain. |

```css
.tnails {
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/200/400">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/300/600">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/300/500">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
<img class="tnails" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
```

Comment: ty for your response! but object-fit cover crops the images. I need to apply this enmasse to a large number of images so if I use object-fit cover the truck image is good but then there are many other images that get cropped. when i use object-fit contain they all work it is only the one specific truck image. do you have any idea why it is not filling the entire container? ty!

Comment: @iloveJesus91 are the images smaller than 180px?

Comment: yes,some of them are.

Comment: @iloveJesus91 Maybe you can specify a `min-width` and `min-height` and `aspect-ratio`?

Comment: ok I can try that, what min-width,height and aspect ratio should I set?